# Can I apply Dominated convergence theorem?

Tags: convergence-divergence, lebesgue-measure

I'm considering a regression problem: $Y=f(\mathbf X)$ with $\mathbf X \in \mathbb R^d$. There exists a sequence of functions $(f_n)$ such that $\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty}f_n(\mathbf x)=f(\mathbf x)$.

Now, let $\phi_n=f_n(z_{k,j},\mathbf x_{-j})-f_n(z_{k-1,j},\mathbf x_{-j})$ denote the finite change in the response variable by varying only the j-th component of $\mathbf X$. I chose $z_{k,j}$ as the $\frac{k}{K}$ quantile of the empirical distribution of $\{f(x_{i,j}) : i = 1,..,n\}$ with $z_{0,j}$ chosen just below the smallest observation, and $z_{K,j}$ chosen as the largest observation.

My question is: assuming that the assumptions of the Lebesgue's dominated convergence theorem hold, can I exchange the variance with the operation of the limit, i.e. it is true that:
\begin{equation}
 \lim\limits_{n\rightarrow \infty}\text{Var}(\phi_n)= \text{Var}(\phi)
\end{equation}
where $\phi=f(z_{k,j},\mathbf x_{-i})-f(z_{k-1,j},\mathbf x_{-i})$.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the assumptions of the dominated convergence theorem hold, then you have that:
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \text{Var}(\phi_n)&=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \mathbb{E}[\phi_n^2]-(\mathbb{E}[\phi_n])^2\\
&=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\mathbb{E}[\phi_n^2]-(\mathbb{E}[\phi])^2
\end{split}
\end{equation}
However, to ensure that the $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\mathbb{E}[\phi_n^2]=\mathbb{E}[\phi^2]$, you also need the assumptions for the dominated convergence theorem to hold for the sequence $\{\phi_n^2\}_{n=1}^\infty$. Do you have this?

Comment: I think so, but I have to verify them. Thank you so much for your help.